# React Native: Convert the value stored in AsyncStorage into an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I am making a simple CRUD app using React Native with MongoDB, NodeJS and Express. When the user registers, the _id is saved inside AsyncStorage to check if the user is already authenticated or not every time he/she opens the app.

```
const response = await axios.post('API_LINK', {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                })
const data = await response.data
console.log(data)
await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', data.user._id)
```

console.log(data) returns

```
Object {
  "user": Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "62e42244b7bc9e7f9de5131b",
    "email": "testing5@gmail.com",
    "name": "Test 5",
    "password": "$2a$10$SE7Eq46mBXGw7FYBtOtqqO49wvIMYDl0LfHknrrp.rWdrYNr6Dk8.",
    "projects": Array [],
  },
}
```

The `projects []` contains all the projects created by that particular user. So, in the `Project Model and Controller`, the `userId` is also passed, so that the specific project is stored in the projects array of that specific user whose userId is passed.

ProjectModel

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    },
    description: {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
})
```

Project Controller

```
export const createProject = async (req, res, next) => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    let userExists
    try {
        userExists = await User.find(user)
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    const project = new Project({
        title,
        description,
        user
    })
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

CreateProject

```
const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')
const response = await axios.post('http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/api/project/create', {
                    title: title.trim(),
                    description: description.trim(),
                    image: image.trim(),
                    user: userId
                })
```

But on clicking `Create` button, this error is shown
`ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got 62e42244b7bc9e7f9de5131b`, linking to the `createProject` inside Project Controller.

Then, I saw that `_id stored as userId` is `string`, so I tried to convert it to `object` using `JSON.parse()`.

```
const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')
const userId2 = JSON.parse(userId)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
user: userId2
```

But, now I get this error `JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string`.
So, how to convert the `userId` stored in AsyncStorage into `object`? And, if there are any other better methods to perform this task, please suggest.

Comment: In `ProjectController` where is `User` and `user` initialized?

Comment: The `User` in `ProjectController` is imported from User Model